# Android: OnTouchListener.OnTouch not called in multiTouch

Tags: android, multi-touch, ontouchlistener

I implemented multitouching buttons in my app, by definyng and attaching my version of OnTouchListener (and onTouch method) to all my buttons.
All works perfectly, except for one thing which seems to belong to standard behaviour of the listener. I hope to be able to explain it without posting code since it's long.

If I click and hold a button, the onTouch method is called, as expected, and application sees button clicked.
If I click and hold a second one, the onTouch method (related to first button) is called, as expected, and application sees button clicked.

If I release only second one, if my finger on the first button stays ABSOLUTELY motionless, the onTouch event is not called and the second button is not logically released. The onTouch method gets called only if I move at least a pixel first finger, and only in that moment the second button gets released.

I know that it's very difficult to keep a finger exactly in the same position for more than one millisecond :-),  but sometimes it happens..I had to spend some time in order to understand the reason for this behaviour, and I didn't find a solution, have you got any suggests to workaround this problem?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your onTouch

```
PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        float xDiff = Math.abs(curr.x-start.x);
        float yDiff = Math.abs(curr.y-start.y);
        if (xDiff < 5f && yDiff < 5f) {
        //insert here your code when button is click
        }
     break;
```

It's help for me avoid inaccuracy of push.

Comment: Hello, thank you but my problem is that the onTouch is not called :-) Maybe I'll have to create a different listener of the same class for each button